# Magento 2 one step checkout not capturing abandoned email in quote Table

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, extensions

I am using BSS one step checkout extension.

Here I see the after filling checkout form the Guest user information not saving under quote table in db. So what should I do to save guest customer information in quote table when guest customer put email.

here is video showing about user and Guest user: http://somup.com/cqXFjvfbW6